# Items is not able to set in recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Adapter code

```
 public class ButtonGroupAdp extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ButtonGroupAdp.MyViewHolder> {


    List<ButtonGroup> mList;

    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    Context context;
    private int screenWidth;

    public ButtonGroupAdp(List<ButtonGroup> mList, Context context) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.context = context;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView txtTitle;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_groupname, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ButtonGroup datum = mList.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText("" + datum.getGroupName());
        datum.notifyAll();


    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
}
```

This is my main activity code

```
badp = new ButtonGroupAdp(mlist, this);

    mlist = new ArrayList<>();
    mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site);
   myRecyclerView.setAdapter(badp);
```

This is where m getting values from sqlite

```
 public List<ButtonGroup> getAllProductList(String siteCode) {
    List<ButtonGroup> buttonGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT groupName,groupId FROM ButtonGroups where parentGroupId='"+null+"' and siteCode='"+siteCode+"'", null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));
            buttonGroups.add(buttonGroup);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return buttonGroups;
}
```

Basically i want to put this data in my horizontal recycler view and on touch of each item i should get to know about which one is click but dont know why m facing this error please help me
This is the Error am getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mobex.inapp, PID: 17931
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.mobex.inapp.Adapter.ButtonGroupAdp.getItemCount(ButtonGroupAdp.java:81)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3534)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your mList before passing it to the ButtonGroupAdp

This should be solving it.

**Just replace**

```
List<ButtonGroup> mList;
```

**With**

```
List<ButtonGroup> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**UPDATE**

Change this

```
badp = new ButtonGroupAdp(mlist, this);
    mlist = new ArrayList<>();
    mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site);
   myRecyclerView.setAdapter(badp);
```

To

```
mlist = new ArrayList<>();
badp = new ButtonGroupAdp(mlist, this);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(badp);
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site);
badp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yes the issue resolve but the data is not set on adapter

Comment: if not, please add mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

Comment: Please check my updated answer, for your horizontal recycler view

Comment: Updated but still no data is shown on recycler view.

Comment: mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site); try to change this to mlist.addAll(mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site)); then notifyDataSetChanged on adapter

Comment: m getting mlist as 0 in adapter

Comment: oh! Then recheck your queries and everything should work fine. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Your `mlist` is `null`

Yor first need to initialize your `mlist` then pass it into your `ButtonGroupAdp` adapter like below code

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
mlist = new ArrayList<>();
badp = new ButtonGroupAdp(mlist, this);
mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(badp);
```

**UPDATE**

You need to `notify` you adapter after adding data in your ArrayList

```
mlist = new ArrayList<>();
adp = new ButtonGroupAdp(mlist, this);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(badp);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mlist =  mobexInAppDb.getAllProductList(site);
adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yes the issue is resolve but the data is not set on adapter

Comment: Bro nothing changed please have a look once on my adapter code i guess i have done some mistakes there

Comment: @Ashishgupta just `setLayoutManager` to your `mRecyclerView`

Comment: @Ashishgupta make sure your list in not empty inside `getAllProductList()` method try to print size of list after adding data in your list

Comment: there is data because while going on that method getAllproductList m getting 10 data i have debugged and checked it